# Use Cycles baking for Blenders internal renderer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, normal-map

I started modeling a house that I want to use in a game. I really like the workflow of nodes if it comes to materials. So I decided to use the cycles renderer in 'material view' for modeling, texturing and baking.
I created some normal and spec maps but did not see the effect in 'material view' as if I use the BI renderer. Ok that makes sense somehow.. Cycles must be calculating the effects based on rays and rays are only traced in 'render view'?!
Do I have to change all my node based materials and switch to BI materials now to see my normalmaps applied in realtime? I still would like to use Cycles for baking.. so I still need the node based materials. Can I set up a material for every renderer and switch between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to be organized , save the models in one blend file with no material , in a separate blend file you [link the models](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23155/2816) in and set up their materials. this will guarantee no material mixup happens and your blend file project will be cleaner.

you could also make a separate scene for each renderer (e.g a cycles scene and internal scene , a bake scene)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Unfortunately I am a beginner and I guess that using multiple blend files to organize my project would confuse me more that it would help.

Comment: It's not hard at all. You just select the object from the file's internal directory and it shows up in your opened file. Anything you do to the linked copy stays with the linked copy. You can still make changes to the original mesh and it affects all linked copies. Just name the files in a way that is understandable.

Comment: @Luca Hofmann It's the best solution for the problem. If your PC can handle it, you can open another Blender Instance and view your model in Blender BI there. All you have to do is reload the file after you changed the mesh or the baked materials in the original file.