# How to combine two Blender projects

Tags: objects, blend-files

I am making an apple with a face and I made the actual body and the face separate. Both parts are in different files and I was wondering how I can merge them into one file so I can attach them together.

Comment: related: [how to reuse elements from existing blend file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81/how-can-i-reuse-existing-materials-objects-etc-from-an-existing-blend) and [difference between linking and appending](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23153/what-is-the-differance-between-linking-and-appending-an-external-blend)

Answer (score 1):

just append the files from one file to another. just do FILE>APPEND and you are ready to import objects from one scene to aother